# Unable to upgrade edition of Windows Server 2016 (Standard -> DataCenter)

Tags: windows-server-2016, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Windows server 2016 from Standard to DataCenter using the   command `dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenter /ProductKey:MY-WORKING-MSDN-KEY /AcceptEula` .  Unfortunatelly it ends with error 14081.

In the dism.log I have the following:

```
2019-04-06 21:11:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4204 TID=5000  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80073701) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2019-04-06 21:11:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80073701)
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x80073701)
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 Package manager failed to process changes - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents(hr:0x80073701)
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed to update components - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents(hr:0x80073701)
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed to update components from [ServerStandard] to [ServerDatacenter] - CTransmogManager::TransmogrifyWorker
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 [Upgrading system]: An error occurred while operating system components were being updated. The upgrade cannot proceed.
For more information, review the log file.
 [hrError=0x80073701] - CTransmogManager::EventError
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed to Upgrade! - CTransmogManager::TransmogrifyWorker(hr:0x80073701)
2019-04-06 21:11:30, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=4204 TID=3272 Failed to upgrade! - CTransmogManager::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80073701)
```

The same command works on other system without problems with the same key.

Can you please be so kind and help me ? The command `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth` shows nothing and I really do not know what to do except reinstalling the whole server.

dism /online /get-currentedition shows:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.2457

Current edition is:

Current Edition : ServerStandard

The operation completed successfully.
```

dism /online /get-targeteditions shows

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.2457

Editions that can be upgraded to:

Target Edition : ServerDatacenter

The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: Is the server connected to the Internet? Does it use a WSUS server? Did you run `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: Server is under NAT connected to the internet, WSUS I am not using, sfc /scannow shows "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations".

Comment: One question, is the Server 2016 Standard installation activated or is it still in Evaluation Mode? What Is the result from "/dism /online /get-currentedition" and "/dism /online /get-targeteditions" BR

Comment: @Schnarchnase added answer to question